# Writing a glob exclude string in AWS Glue Crawler

Tags: glob, aws-glue

I'm trying to create a crawler in AWS Glue. My analytics program is dropping a bunch of files in S3 in 5 minute batches with several different partitions. It essentially creates a folder structure like this:

1. Analytics

   - 2018-03-27T00:00:00.000Z
   - - Session
   - - Search
   - - DirectURL
   - - PageData
   - 2018-03-27T00:00:05.000Z
   - - Session
   - - Search
   - - DirectURL
   - - PageData

I'm really want to create an include string, but it seems you can only do an exclude string in AWS Glue Crawler interface. I really just want to grab the files in the Session folder.

If I want to grab everything except for the Session folder I can do this:

{Session}/**

I was assuming to do the opposite I just needed to do this, but it isn't working:

{!Session}/**

Any ideas/help?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Having exclusion behavior might not be the best choice at all, since you loose control of what will be picked up by the crawler. Using include-statements might be better. The only exclude-support is using ! inside [] as stated in the doc, but that will only handle single characters:

> Brackets [ ] create a bracket expression that matches a single character of a name component out of a set of characters. For example, [abc] matches a, b, or c. The hyphen (-) can be used to specify a range, so [a-z] specifies a range that matches from a through z (inclusive). These forms can be mixed, so [abce-g] matches a, b, c, e, f, or g. If the character after the bracket ([) is an exclamation point (!), the bracket expression is negated. For example, [!a-c] matches any character except a, b, or c.

Take a look at the doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html

Comment: I think this wouldn't work because `[ ]` considered everything inside it as individual characters, and not as a string

Comment: You are correct. How about breaking it up in one bracket per letter? Something tells me that there is a better solution.

Comment: No, that wouldn't alter the behaviour. Turns of GLOB patterns do not support exclusion

Comment: Having exclusion behavior might not be the best choice at all, since you loose control of what will be picked up by the crawler. Using include-statements will be better.